# How to make a JOptionPane "OK" itself from a child widget on double-click

Tags: java, swing, dialog

I have a JOptionPane created with .showConfirmDialog. Within that is a JPanel containing "stuff" (it's actually a custom project browser for selecting a project to open).

It's all working fine - I select a project to open, and press OK, and I can get at the selected project from the calling class.  That's all perfect.

However, what I want to do is to be able to double-click an item and have it press "OK" on the panel for me. The double-click side of things is not a problem. What I can't work out is how to make it perform the OK press.

I create the dialog with:

```
OpenBookPanel info = new OpenBookPanel();
int r = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, info, "Open Book", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
if (r == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
    ... etc ...
```

And `OpenBookPanel` is just an extension of `JPanel` containing a `JScrollPane` and a `JTable` with its own cell renderer and custom model (source available [here](https://github.com/MajenkoProjects/AudiobookRecorder/blob/master/src/uk/co/majenko/audiobookrecorder/OpenBookPanel.java) if you want it).

I guess I can walk up the object tree to get to the surrounding dialog from within the `OpenBookPanel` object, but what would I do then?

Comment: Have you considered creating your own Dialog? Then you can add your own OK button and click it programmatically

Comment: Actually, quite by chance while experimenting with various things I just found the answer...

Comment: Interesting, thanks for sharing the answer!

Comment: Yeah. It took me by surprise. I was expecting it to just set a value internally and nothing else. The actual closing of the dialog was very unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

While experimenting I quite by chance stumbled across the answer (it's not documented in the documents...)

Step one is to walk up the tree to find the JOptionPane object.  This is in a MouseEvent Listener looking for a double click:

```
Component c = (Component)OpenBookPanel.this;
while ((c != null) && (!(c instanceof JOptionPane))) {
    c = c.getParent();
}
```

If `c` is not `null` then you have found the JOptionPane.  So you can then cast it properly.

Now the magic bit.  `JOptionPane` has a `setValue` method:

> public void setValue(Object newValue)
>
> Sets the value the user has chosen.
>
> Parameters:
>
> newValue - the chosen value
>
> See Also:
>
> getValue()

Call that with `JOptionPane.OK_OPTION` to set the value of the option you want to choose.  Now - what the docs *don't* mention is that it doesn't just set the value: it actively *chooses* the value. It acts as if the user had actually interacted with the dialog to select the option.  The moment you set the value using that function the dialog closes and the selected value is returned.

Here's my completed MouseEvent Listener for reference:

```
table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getClickCount() == 2 && table.getSelectedRow() != -1) {
            Component c = (Component)OpenBookPanel.this;
            while ((c != null) && (!(c instanceof JOptionPane))) {
                c = c.getParent();
            }
            if (c == null) {
                System.err.println("Could not get option pane!");
            } else {
                JOptionPane op = (JOptionPane)c;
                op.setValue(JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
            }
        }
    }
});
```